# Efficiently copying slices of large numpy arrays to a smaller array of continuous memory

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have a need for copying slices from a large numpy array to another smaller array as efficiently as possible. Ultimately, the smaller array will be passed as a two dimensional array into a C function for processing. Because of this, the subarray data must be copied within a continuous block of memory.

In the example below, I am attempting to pre-allocate the The smaller array (*aa*) to be efficient but I think this results in a newly created array before making the copying on each iteration.

```
import numpy as np

M=1024
N=8
a = np.zeros((2,M),dtype=np.float32,order='C')
aa = np.zeros((2,N),dtype=np.float32,order='C')
for n in xrange(M/N):
    aa = a[:,n*N:n*N+N]
    #pass array to c function - e.g. foo(aa,aa.shape[0],aa.shape[1])
    print aa
    a[:,n*N:n*N+N] = aa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do `aa[:] = a[:, n*N:n*N+N]`, so that the data from `a` is copied into the pre-existing `aa` array, rather than having a new one created in each iteration, and the other thrown away.

**EDIT** Thinking twice about the OP's case, because the subarrays are extracted with slicing, `aa` will not be a new array in each iteration, but a new view into the array `a`. So it will not be contiguous, which is probably a bigger concern than performance. The originally allocated `aa` array is garbage collected unused in the first iteration.

Comment: I've always wondered about this. So, if `aa` is initialized as an array, `aa[:] = ...` copies the data into the pre-existing array? Whereas if we write `aa = a[...]` it over-writes `aa`with `a[...]`?

Comment: Sort of. When you add the `[:]` you trigger a call to the ndarray's `__setitem__` method, which tries to copy the rhs into the array. If you don't, then normal Python semantics are at work, and you are assigning the label on the lhs to point to the object on the rhs. If the lhs label was pointing to something else, it no longer will, and thus it will likely be garbage collected.